# Terminating a REST service returns HTTP 200. How to deal with errors then?

Tags: rest

I am testing my REST service in spring boot. I have added a debug point in service entry. For testing errors when service might cease in memory, I terminate the application manually. but this returns 200 status code? after successful processing also, it returns 200. How should I proceed with this 'termination' error scenario because, in the client side, the status code 200 means successful processing!

Comment: Wait, so you have two servers, say server1 contacts server2 over HTTP. If you kill server2, server1 still receives 2xx when contacting server2?

Comment: "For testing errors when service might cease in memory, I terminate the application manually." - how are you doing this?

Comment: I mean just kill the process in IDE once the service debug point is reached before actual processing begins.

Comment: @sp00m Just a postman call is enough where postman is a client.